# Insert into Mysql and get unique id

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have following:
index.php

```
<form method="get" action="rezultat.php" name="form-area" id="form-area" class="form-area" />
   <h4>Informatii despre prieten</h4>

   <input type="text" id="name" name="nu" placeholder="" maxlength="25" required />
   <input type="text" id="name" name="pr" placeholder="" maxlength="25" required />
   <input type="text" id="name" name="va" placeholder="" maxlength="2" required  />
   <input type="text" id="name" name="lo" placeholder="" maxlength="25" required />

   <h4>Informatii despre tine</h4>

   <input type="text" id="name" name="np" placeholder="" maxlength="25" required />    
   <input type="text" id="name" name="pn" placeholder="" maxlength="4" required />

   <select name="stire" required >
       <option value="Nu ai selectat">Selecteaza</option>
       <option value="0">................................ </option>
       <option value="Bautor de sperma">[MASCULIN] - Bautor de sperma </option>
       <option value="Protest in chiloti">[MASCULIN] - Protest in chiloti </option>
       <option value="Si-a taiat penisul">[MASCULIN] - Si-a taiat penisul </option>
       <option value="Masturbare in public">[MASCULIN] - Masturbare in public </option>
       <option value="Fan Facebook">[MASCULIN] - Fan Facebook </option>
       <option value="0">................................ </option>
       <option value="Prostituata anului">[FEMININ] - Prostituata anului </option>
       <option value="Cu sanii la vedere">[FEMININ] - Cu sanii la vedere </option>
       <option value="Sex oral in public">[FEMININ] - Sex oral in public </option>
       <option value="A violat un mos">[FEMININ] - A violat un mos </option>
       <option value="Miss Urzica">[FEMININ] - Miss Urzica </option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />  
</form>
```

rezultat.php

```
    <?php include 'config.php'; include 'colectare.php'; ?>
    <? echo $link; ?> //that show url link
```

config.php

```
    <?php
    $host="localhost";
    $user_name="USER";
    $pwd="PWD";
    $database_name="DB";

    $conexiune = mysql_connect($host,$user_name,$pwd) or die("Nu ma pot conecta la MySQL!");
     mysql_select_db($database_name, $conexiune) or die("Nu gasesc baza de date");

    $adresa="http://site.com/";
    ?>
```

colectare.php

```
    <?

    $host="localhost";
    $user_name="USER";
    $pwd="PWD";
    $database_name="DB";
    $db=mysql_connect($host, $user_name, $pwd);
    if (mysql_error() > "") print mysql_error() . "<br>";
    mysql_select_db($database_name, $db);
    if (mysql_error() > "") print mysql_error() . "<br>";

      $find = array ("/ /");

      $replace = array ("+");

      $link = $adresa.'stiri.php?        pn='.ucwords($_GET["pn"]).'&nu='.ucwords($_GET["nu"]).'&pr='.ucwords($_GET["pr"]).'&va='.ucwords($_GET["va"]).'&lo='.ucwords($_GET["lo"]).'&stire='.$_GET["stire"];

      $link = preg_replace($find,$replace,$link);

      $stire = $_GET["stire"];

      $np = htmlentities($_GET['np'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5);

      $pn = $_GET["pn"];

      $datetime = gmDate('Y-m-d H:i:s');




      $query = "insert into stiri (url, stire, np, pn, hits, datetime) values ('" . $link . "', '" . $stire . "', '" . $np . "', '" . $pn . "', '" . $hits . "',  NOW())";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

      ?>
```

stiri.php

```
    <? include_once "config.php"; ?>

      <?

      $find = array ("+");
      $replace = array ("/ /");
      $pn = ucwords($_GET["pn"]);
      $nu = ucwords($_GET["nu"]); 
      $pr = ucwords($_GET["pr"]); 
      $va = ucwords($_GET["va"]); 
      $lo = ucwords($_GET["lo"]); 
      $stire = $_GET["stire"];    
      ?>

    <?php
    if($stire == "Bautor de sperma"){  // TITLUL FARSEI
       echo include("bautor-de-sperma.php");   // PAGINA PHP A FARSEI
    }
    elseif($stire == "Protest in chiloti"){       // TITLUL FARSEI
       echo include("protest.php");   // PAGINA PHP A FARSEI
    }
    elseif($stire == "Si-a taiat penisul"){       // TITLUL FARSEI
       echo include("taiat.php");   // PAGINA PHP A FARSEI
    }
    elseif($stire == "Masturbare in public"){       // TITLUL FARSEI
       echo include("masturbare.php");   // PAGINA PHP A FARSEI
    }
    elseif($stire == "Fan Facebook"){       // TITLUL FARSEI
       echo include("facebook.php");   // PAGINA PHP A FARSEI
    }
    elseif($stire == "Prostituata anului"){       // TITLUL FARSEI
       echo include("prostituata.php");   // PAGINA PHP A FARSEI
    }
    elseif($stire == "Cu sanii la vedere"){       // TITLUL FARSEI
       echo include("sani.php");   // PAGINA PHP A FARSEI
    }
    elseif($stire == "Sex oral in public"){       // TITLUL FARSEI
       echo include("sex.php");   // PAGINA PHP A FARSEI
    }
    elseif($stire == "A violat un mos"){       // TITLUL FARSEI
       echo include("viol.php");   // PAGINA PHP A FARSEI
    }
    elseif($stire == "Miss Urzica"){    
       echo include("urzica.php");  
    }

    else
    {
      echo "Ne pare rau, insa aceasta stire nu mai exista. Vezi mai multe <a         href='http://site.ro'>AICI</a>";
    }
    ?>
```

and i give u and one page, urzica.php for example wich contain following::

```
    <? echo $nu; ?> , <? echo $pr; ?> , <? echo $va; ?> , <? echo $lo; ?>
```

With that metod, all informations are stored in database, but link it's show all informations, cuz i use get method .
The link its offered like that: 
http://site.ro/stiri.php?pn=SOMETHING&nu=SOMETHING&pr=SOMETHING&va=SOMETHING&lo=SOMETHING&stire=SELECTED-ONE

I want to use post method, and that complicated my brain, and to show me something like that:
http://site.ro/stire.php?nume=NAME-FROM-SELECT-FORM

I hope to understand something guys

Comment: Great! Do you have any specific question relevant to tags that you used in your question (mysql, php)?

Comment: site will use php and mysql. im newbie on that, so pls understand me!

Comment: 1. the form is HTML not PHP. 2. what is your problem ? 3. show us #2 with your PHP code example, what did you try to achieve vs. actual result etc.

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are **no longer maintained** and shouldn't be used in any new codebase. It is being phased out in favor of newer APIs. Instead you should use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli).

Comment: HAHA ! Your "content" is awesome. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% certain what you're after, but this MySQL class should help. Basically, all your operations on the database go through here, and you will get that unique id you want on MySQL INSERT commands:

https://gist.github.com/jbnunn/6297071

To use it, set up your connection parameters:

```
$db_host     = 'localhost';
$db_username = 'USER';
$db_password = 'PWD';
$db_database = 'DB';

$GLOBALS['db'] = new MySQL($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);     
if(!function_exists("getDB")) {
  function getDB() {
    return($GLOBALS['db']);
  }
}
```

Then, in your code, require that MySQL class,

```
require_once('mysql.php')
```

and make inserts like:

```
$db = getDB();
$id = $db->insert("insert into stiri (url, stire, np, pn, hits, datetime) values ('" . $link . "', '" . $stire . "', '" . $np . "', '" . $pn . "', '" . $hits . "',  NOW())");
```

and get the row's ID from the `$id` variable.

To get data out of your database, you could make queries via methods like this:

```
$result = $db->execute("SELECT * FROM stiri WHERE id = '$id'");
```

Comment: Great--if that works for you, don't forget to click the check mark to accept this answer

Comment: last question: how can i display info added to database, in urzica.php page for exmple.. it must show "nu , pr , va , lo" , but i have and 9 more pages.. look in select menu. i hope to understand me :)

Comment: In urzica.php, get the data you want. I think this will work: `$data = $db->execute("SELECT * FROM stiri WHERE id = '" . $_REQUEST['id'] . "' LIMIT 1");`

Then, echo your data out like this: `echo $data['nu']` or `echo $data['pr'];`

Comment: One more question.. How must i change following to get id?        $link = $adresa.'stiri.php?pn='.ucwords($_GET["pn"]).'&nu='.ucwords($_GET["nu"]).'&pr='.ucwords($_GET["pr"]).'&va='.ucwords($_GET["va"]).'&lo='.ucwords($_GET["lo"]).'&stire='.$_GET["stire"];